# Selenium sometimes returns a blank page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I try to open an URL through Selenium, after Google Chrome opened and it showed a blank page.

But when I copied this URL to a new TAB and opened it, it could be displayed normally.

This scene is sporadic，most of the time it doesn't happened.

Here is most of my code:

```
server_path = '../browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy.bat'
server_opetion = {'prot':8080,'use-littleproxy':False}
server = Server(path=server_path,options=server_options)
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--proxy-server={0}.format(proxy.proxy))
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',['enable-automation'])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',['enable-logging'])

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe',options=options)
except Exception as e:
    latest_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(latest_driver,options = options)

driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
proxy.new_bar('google',options={'captureHeaders':True,'captureContent':True})
driver.get('url')
```

- the google chrome version: 115.0.5790.171
- selenium version: 4.9.0

[image]

Please help me with this issue.